# Reset input fields after submission

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm working on an asp.net core project. I have some issues with the reset button. when I enter data which is already saved. The error message is shown as I given. After this reset button is not working.

Comment: Need clarity with sample code, It will be helpfull,

Comment: Please post relevant parts of the code that you tried.

Comment: You can press F12 to see any error in browser. this error always from the jquery and show all of them in the console tab.
check js code and clear any error.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest after the submit, to either reset them with javascript, either if you use a post back, redirect to the same page (without post back this time).

For example this core redirects to him self, and the form is clear now.

```
Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
```

Or you can use this javascript code together and avoid the post back

```
OnClientClick="return (confirm('Clear Form ?') && this.form.reset(),false)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is very unclear, but it sounds like what you're talking about is actually the client-side validation. Once validation has been activated (by entering something into a field), validation will remain active. If you then clear that field (using the reset button, for example) and it's required, you'll still have a message saying the field is required, because it is, and it's now empty. If you want to clear all these validation messages, as well, then you need to do something like:

```
$('[type=reset]').on('click', function () {
    let validator = $(this).closest('form').validate();
    validator.resetForm();
});
```